# How to fix "Unable to find free port" error in Java (android)

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver

I create an application to automate task on website. When I will try create new Webdriver and run emulator, app immediately stop and i receive error: "Unable to find a free port"
How can i fix that?
Screen with error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vKkT.jpg

Comment: Are you using Eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your JAVA_HOME pointing to some shared drive.
 If you run your Selenium test from Eclipse IDE, check in Eclipse > Window > Preference > Java > Installed JRE. The active (tick mark selected) should point to local drive's JRE path (Check the column 'Location'). If not, then add local JRE from C:\Program Files\Java\JDK path. Restart your IDE and run now.